# Transparent PNG with white edges

Tags: graphics, png

For some reason this PNG with a transparent background shows up with white edges but only when on a grey background of nearly the same shade, it's fine on black or light grey.

It's 24bit file and done the same way I done many times before in photoshop with no problems.

[image: News PNG]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because it is antialiased against a white background. Try saving your PNG in proper 32 bit?

Comment: Photoshop only exports 24 bit which normally works fine. It's on a transparent background.

Answer (score 0):

The antialiasing of the letters did not use any alpha value, they just rendered against your default background color. Anyway, it doesn't look fine on black, I saw the hard antialiased pixels immediately ;)

Comment: I did not talk about white edges, I talk about the hard aliased pixels (which are not white). Maybe you don't recognize them, because the color is near to the font color. But I did.